# defining a function acting on a matrix in python

Tags: python, function, matrix

I want to define a reasonably simple function to swap two entries in a matrix, currently I have the following code:

```
def swap (n[a][b] ,direction):

    if direction==1:             #to the left
        entry=n[a][b]
        n[a][b]=n[a-1][b]
        n[a-1][b]=entry
```

I'm struggling to find a way to make it so that when I enter a variable e.g. `current` (where `current =matrix[3][2]`) the contents of the `if` clause act with `a=3 ,b=2` on the target matrix.

Comment: That is not valid Python syntax - you should have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Python has no way of knowing that `current` came from `matrix[3][2]`. `current` may even be present in different places in different matrices at the same time. You'll have to pass in the matrix and the indices explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but at least it is working python code:

```
import numpy as np

def swap(M, a, b, direction):
     if direction == 1:
         entry = M[a,b]
         M[a,b] = M[a-1,b]
         M[a-1,b] = entry

#create a test matrix
np.random.seed(10)
n = np.random.rand(10, 100, size=(3,2))

print n
n = swap(n,2,1,1)
print n
```

This outputs:

```
[[19 25]
 [74 38]
 [99 39]]

[[19 25]
 [74 39]
 [99 38]]
```

So the 38 and 39 were swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @interjay comment, here is a working function (assuming that matrix is list of lists):

```
def swap(m, r, c, direction):
    if direction == 1:
        m[r][c], m[r-1][c] = m[r-1][c], m[r][c]
```

parameters:

- `m` is matrix you want to act on,
- `r` is a row of the element you want to swap,
- `c` is a column of the element you want to swap,
- `direction` is direction of swap.

Usage example:

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print A
swap(A, 1, 1, 1)
print A
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 4], [3, 2]]
```

Also note, that usually, but not necessary, first index corresponds to row or line and second corresponds to column. In this case so swapping `n[a][b]` with `n[a-1][b]` in your code is equivalent to moving element n[a][b] upwards one row, not to the left.